# Sitecore SXA Base Theme script issue

Tags: sxa

I would like to ask could we move these scripts from `body` tag to `head` tag? Because i want to add the defer attribute for these scripts.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to modify the `SxaLayout.cshtml` file to do this. If you look at the file, at the top it gets all the asset links:

```
@{
    AssetLinks assetLinks = AssetLinksGenerator.GenerateLinks(new ThemesProvider());
}
```

Once it has those, it renders the styles in the head and the scripts just before the body close:

```
    @foreach (string script in assetLinks.Scripts)
    {
        @Html.Raw(script)
    }
</body>
```

You would first need to move that to the head in the layout. To add the defer attribute is going to require you to modify the `AssetLinksGenerator.GenerateLinks` method. If you decompile that method and follow it through, you will see that the `<script>` tags are hard coded. For the base themes, the method is called `GetLinks` - you can inherit and override that method tho.

These are the decompiled lines:

```
    foreach (string str in result1.Styles.Select<string, string>((Func<string, string>) (link => "<link href=\"" + link + "\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />")))
      result.Styles.Add(str);
    foreach (string str in result1.Scripts.Select<string, string>((Func<string, string>) (link => "<script src=\"" + link + "\"></script>")))
      result.Scripts.Add(str);
```

Modify that and add your defer attribute in.